# Deserialize json as object from 3 properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Suppose that I have some json that has 3 objects and values

```
{
    "SomeProperty": "42",
    "Foo": "bar",
    "Name001": "ABC_1",
    "Type001": "D",
    "Confidence001": "100",
    ...
    "Name00N": "ABC_N",
    "Type00N": "D",
    "Confidence00N": "50",

}
```

How would I use a converter/mapper to group those 3 objects into a single POCO?

```
public class DeserializedJsonClass
{
    public long SomeProperty {get;set;}
    public string Foo {get;set;}
    public EvaluationStat[] Evaluations {get;set;}
}
public class EvaluationStat
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public char Type {get;set;}
    public int Confidence {get;set;}
}
```

I've learned about the mapping that Newtonsoft has, and I use the converter to convert Y/N to `bool` and some xml into a `XDocument` but I can't figure out how to map those 3 objects into one.

Comment: Do you have control over the source Json? The shown sample is going to be difficult to map since the names of the properties are different in each item `Name001` vs `Name00N`

Comment: I don't but it is from 1 to N times (max of 100)

Comment: In that case, you are going to have to deserialize into a Dictionary<String, String> and write some custom code to extract the elements programmatically. There isn't going to be a pretty solution.

Comment: This looks like "`json`" in name only. If you remove the opening and closing braces `{...}`, it's flat file / CSV data :). Like @SilasReinagel has suggested, you are better off deserializing this into a `Dictionary<string,string>` if you know that the "key" values will be unique (or use `List<NameValuePair<string,string>>` if you expect duplicates) and then write custom code to programatically extract elements and populate array.

Comment: The json sample I provided is a part of the whole. I had a feeling that we might be doing it wrong... :(

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it:

```
public class DeserializedJsonClass
{
    public long SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EvaluationStat> Evaluations { get; set; }
}

public class EvaluationStat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public char Type { get; set; }
    public int Confidence { get; set; }
}


// ...

private static DeserializedJsonClass Deserialize(string json)
{
    // using Newtonsoft.Json
    dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    DeserializedJsonClass result = new DeserializedJsonClass();
    result.SomeProperty = deserialized.SomeProperty;
    result.Foo = deserialized.Foo;
    result.Evaluations = FetchEvaluations(deserialized);
    return result;
}

private static IEnumerable<EvaluationStat> FetchEvaluations(dynamic json)
{
    ICollection<string> names = new List<string>();
    ICollection<char> types = new List<char>();
    ICollection<int> confidences = new List<int>();

    foreach (var prop in json)
    {
        if (prop.Name.StartsWith("Name"))
           names.Add((string)prop.Value.Value);
        else if (prop.Name.StartsWith("Type"))
           types.Add(Convert.ToChar((string)prop.Value.Value));
        else if (prop.Name.StartsWith("Confidence"))
           confidences.Add(Convert.ToInt32((string)prop.Value.Value));
    }

    return names.Zip(types, (n, t) => new { Name = n, Type = t })
                .Zip(confidences, (l, c) => new { Name = l.Name, Type = l.Type, Confidence = c })
                .Select(t => new EvaluationStat()
    {
        Name = t.Name,
        Type = t.Type,
        Confidence = t.Confidence
    });
}
```

Comment: So i'm trying to get this one to work, but I think part of the problem is that I didn't mention there were other properties in the json.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the source data, this JSON would be able to be deserialized into the Classes you have proposed.

```
[   
    {   
        "Name": "ABC_1", 
        "Type": "D",
        "Confidence": "100"
    },
    ...
    {   
        "Name": "ABC_N", 
        "Type": "D",
        "Confidence": "50"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom JsonConvert is another way to do it

```
public class EvaluationStatJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType ) { return objectType == typeof( DeserializedJsonClass ); }

        public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            var jsonObject = JObject.Load( reader );
            var properties = typeof( EvaluationStat ).GetProperties();

            var deserializedJsonClass = new DeserializedJsonClass
            {
                Evaluations = new EvaluationStat[jsonObject.Count / properties.Length]
            };

            for( var i = 1; i <= jsonObject.Count / properties.Length; i++ )
            {
                deserializedJsonClass.Evaluations[ i - 1 ] = new EvaluationStat();
                foreach( var field in properties )
                {
                    field.SetValue( deserializedJsonClass.Evaluations[ i - 1 ],
                                    jsonObject[ $"{field.Name}{i:000}" ].ToObject( field.PropertyType ) );
                }
            }
            return deserializedJsonClass;
        }

        public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

then where ever you want use it you can do this

```
var jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jss.Converters.Add( new EvaluationStatJsonConverter() );
            var result =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< DeserializedJsonClass >(
                                                                       "your json content" ),
                                                                       jss );
```

I do agree with the other comments it's quite a hack to get decent solution.